# Laravel - how deferred service provider works?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The official docs say:

> If you open the config/app.php file included with Laravel, you will
>   see a providers array. These are all of the service provider classes
>   that will be loaded for your application. Of course, many of these are
>   "deferred" providers, meaning they will not be loaded on every
>   request, but only when the services they provide are actually needed.

and

> If your provider is only registering bindings in the service
>   container, you may choose to defer its registration until one of the
>   registered bindings is actually needed. Deferring the loading of such
>   a provider will improve the performance of your application, since it
>   is not loaded from the filesystem on every request.

How can I know if a package uses a "deferred" service provider that will not be loaded on every request?

If the defer property is not set, what default value is implied?

...and in the cached manifest at bootstrap/cache/services.php what is the difference between providers, eager, deferred and when?

So, how know if a package will be heavy for the entire application or not?

For example, I want to use the "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable" package that is very simple and uses trait for add functionalities in the model.
But also implements a service provided with bindings that will be used in an observer, how I know if this will be loaded only when I save or edit models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the defer property is not set, what default value is implied?

The default value of `protected $defer` is `false`.

> ...and in the cached manifest at bootstrap/cache/services.php what is the difference between providers, eager, deferred and when?

You answered this your self, so I suppose no elaboration is needed.

> So, how know if a package will be heavy for the entire application or not?

Profile it. Bootstrap your application and test the load. Defer and undefer provides to get a sample.

> For example, I want to use the "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable" package that is very simple and uses trait for add functionalities in the model. But also implements a service provided with bindings that will be used in an observer, how I know if this will be loaded only when I save or edit models?

Any provider that implements the `boot` method cannot be deferred. This package implements the `boot` method. Therefore this is a bootstraped service provider and will be loaded with every request.